# Why is <!--cached--> being added to a wget output randomly?

Tags: bash, wget

I wrote a script to notify me of a change on a web site. I use wget to download the sites html then compare it to one downloaded in the past. The problem is that every few times it checks the site `<!--cached-->` is added after `</html>`. I tried to add --no-cache to wget but this makes no difference.

Why is `<!--cached-->` being added to a wget output randomly? Is this something I can do to prevent this or should I rethink the way that I check the site?

Comment: `--no-cache` is server-side caching, explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40389218/2128797) a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle adds tags similar to that to indicate dynamic pages that can be served from cache to avoid regenerating the page.  It probably indicates that the content hasn't changed from your previous read.  You could just filter it out.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when using the `--mirror` option in recursive retrieval.
From the docs:

> Turn on options suitable for mirroring. This option turns on recursion
>   and time-stamping, sets infinite recursion depth and keeps FTP
>   directory listings. It is currently equivalent to "-r -N -l inf
>   --no-remove-listing".

For such an example of [timestamping](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Time_002dStamping), the first entry after every opening div tag in an html file is stamped with the comments "!--**cached**-DDD, DD MMM YYY HH:MM:SS +4 digit offset-->".