# What is the difference between client cache and server cache

Tags: asp.net

I was asked this question in a job interview, but since I'm new to asp.net didn't know the right answer.

I'd appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

Not much to say on client-side; client browser caches resources by default, unless server explicitly says not to.

In contrast, server doesn't not cache resources unless you explicitly configure it. We have multiple ways of caching at different stages. Most common method is ***Runtime.Caching*** for single instance, and ***Redis Cache*** for Web Farm and Web Garden. In Web Form, we sometimes cache/store ***ViewState*** and ***SessionState*** in SQL Server or State Server to improve the speed.

Too many things to answer for server caching depending on the type of interview - junior or senior level.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. it's a senior level. 
How is storing ViewState and SessionStatr in SQL server improves speed? That sounds odd.. Aren't DB actions slower?

Comment: They are two different things. ***SessionState*** is stored in SQL Server for Web Farm or Web Garden. ***ViewState*** can be stored inside ***SessionState*** *(do not have to store in SQL Server)* to reduce page size.